# Magento display grouped products special price

Tags: magento, e-commerce, php

I am trying to figure out how I display the special price of a grouped product on the catalog page.

For example if i have 5 simple products attatched to my grouped product, how do I display the RRP for those products as well as the special price, on the catalog page?

At the moment it will display on the product page only and magento will fetch the lowest price it can find to display on the catalog page.

Any help is greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default theme, you'll have to modify:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

You can add the prices you'll need like this by passing through the product:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply cobolt, i'm not sure what code i need to add after getPriceHtml, do you have any ideas?